# JQuery two if statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a table of information about cities.  I am trying to get an image (inside a div) to appear when the temperature is less than 32 and the elevation is greater than 1000.

My statement keeps coming up with errors.

```
$("td.condition").each(function(){
  if($("td.elevation").text() > 1000) && ($("td.high_temp").text() < 32)));     
    } 
   $(".ice").show();
});
```

Comment: Reading the errors would be a good first step.  This looks like an odd mixture of syntax errors.  You have an empty `if` block, then you close the function, then you try to have more code after closing the function, then try to close the function *again*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broken structure:

```
$("td.condition").each(function(){
    if($("td.elevation").text() > 1000) && ($("td.high_temp").text() < 32)));
    // The above is an empty "if" because of the semi-colon after it.
    // So it checks the condition, but then doesn't do anything.
}
// Now the anonymous function is closed.
$(".ice").show();
// Which means the above line of code is trying to be passed as an argument to each(), which doesn't make sense.
});
// Then you have a stray } and then close the call to each()
```

If that call to `.show()` is supposed to be inside the `if` block, then you want to put it in a curly-brace block following the `if`:

```
$("td.condition").each(function(){
    if($("td.elevation").text() > 1000) && ($("td.high_temp").text() < 32))) {
        $(".ice").show();
    }
});
```